# Getting error when import card to Hyperledger Composer

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I get the following error when I try to import a card using composer-rest-server multiple mode.

First argument must be a string, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, Array, or array-like object."

It was working fine before. I tried with both composer versions, 0.19.16 and hlfv11, and 0.20 hlfv12 but I get the error.

Also when I want to Authenticate to the REST server by navigating to the value of the authPath property through http://localhost:3000/auth/github I get the following error in my terminal but it successfully backs to composer rest server. When it was working fine I did not get such an error.

"Browse your REST API at http://localhost:3000/explorer
Potential security alert: hidden/protected properties ["password","verificationToken"] are used in query."

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are seeing is due to a dependency in the dependency tree of the composer rest server being broken recently and so any npm installs of composer-rest-server will experience this problem as it will pull in this broken dependency.

Composer 0.19.17 has fixed this problem (and it will also be fixed in 0.20.3 when it is released). You can either move to these versions or you can use the docker image of composer rest server which has already downloaded the dependencies and doesn't include the broken dependency.

Comment: Thanks, I installed version 0.19.17 and the problem solved.